# In deleting account, profile link is invalid

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I am trying to delete my StackExchange account, but it keeps on telling me that my profile URL is invalid. I have tried this URL (https://stackexchange.com/users/5705501/ihaveaquestion) but it does not work. Am I inserting an invalid format or what? I am trying to delete the account on this (https://stackoverflow.com/contact/#) site.

Comment: Where are you trying to put that link? Where says it's invalid?

Comment: You can't delete your network profile since it's not a real account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. I had to take the original link that I had, and instead of 5705501, I inserted the number that is sometimes displayed in the search bar at the top right.